# How to open the search tableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, country-codes

Thanks in advance for help me.

I want to open this type screen

[image]

When user tap on country code like this.!

[image]

I am newbie in iOS Development. I don't know how to do that please help me guys.

Comment: you can take a view for it. In that view a tableview and a textfield for search. when click on country code open this view and after selecting close it

Comment: Try UISearchController

Comment: or you can use tableview with searchcontroller instead

Comment: and how to get country Name and codes with Flag @JeckyModi

Comment: you have your method didselectrowatindexpath in tableview where you can get your selected value from array.

Comment: I used tableView on a new Controller its open on full Screen but i want like 1st image i posted. @JeckyModi

Comment: I told you that use UIView and set it as you want with autolayout or constraints and in that you take tableview and search textfield

Comment: ok. Thanks i will try. @JeckyModi

Comment: @ArchanaSIngh from where did u get flags, country name, and country codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in one of my app..

- If you are presenting country selection ViewController using segue from storyboard, then set the `segue` settings as in following image to present the view with transparent background

[image: SegueSettings]

- If you are presenting your view controller programmatically, set the `modalPresentationStyle` as `OverCurrentContext`

**Code Here:**

```
    let modalView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CountrySelectionViewID")
    modalView?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
    self.presentViewController(modalView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

- Use `UIViewController` with `UITableView` as subview, so that you can set the margins for tableview and set background color to black with alpha value around **0.7**
- Implement a delegate function for your country selection view to know which country is selected

Comment: Thanks I will try after that i will come back to you. @raki